# Pulling Data Down With Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

### I tried different alternatives with Python Selenium with the code below, but I could not pull the data one after the other.

item = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class=' col-md-10']")

url = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class=' col-md-10']/p/a[2]")

```
for i in item:
    isim = i.find_element_by_css_selector("h4").text            
    tel = i.find_element_by_css_selector("p").text
    print(isim)
    print(tel)
       
for z in url:
    link = z.get_attribute('href')     
    print(link)
```

---

**This is how I pull the data with the code above..**

```
Hasan Soylu
 
02122377480

Metin Çakmak

02162385624

Selami Aksoy

02122325882

Hasan Solmaz

02122324893


https://aaaa.com

https://bbbb.com

https://cccc.com

https://dddd.com
```

---

**How can I pull the data in the following way?**

```
Hasan Soylu

02122377480

https://aaaa.com


Metin Çakmak

02162385624

https://bbbb.com


Selami Aksoy

02122325882

https://ccc.com


Hasan Solmaz

02122324893

https://dddd.com
```

Comment: You just want to print this way ? Append those items to a list and print them the way you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve this with a [zip](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/). Something like this: (not tested)

```
item = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class=' col-md-10']")
url = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class=' col-md-10']/p/a[2]")

for i in zip(item,url):
    isim = i[0].find_element_by_css_selector("h4").text            
    tel = i[0].find_element_by_css_selector("p").text
    print(isim)
    print(tel)
    link = i[1].get_attribute('href')
    print(link)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Sefan. I tested the code exactly as I wanted, it works very well.

Comment: @steppe so why don't you accept the answer?